# Is there any chance of my SHA1'd string being non-unique?

Tags: php, duplicates, unique, sha

I have the following snippet where I am constructing a string to send out to the user as an email confirmation code:

```
$confirmation_code = $user_id . time() . date('d-m-Y',time());
$confirmation_code = sha1($confirmation_code);
```

Is there any chance of `$confirmation_code` being duplicated at any step?

NOTE: Please remember that `$user_id` is unique for each user

Comment: Take a look at this related post: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29071/will-sha1-of-email-addresses-always-be-unique#29073

Comment: please consider [this note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash) also

Answer (score 1):

Given that `$user_id` is unique for each user, this should (in theory) mean that your confirmation codes should never clash (be "un-unique")

However, in reality, SHA1 hashes *can* clash (see [this MSDN blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomarcher/archive/2006/05/10/are-hash-codes-unique.aspx) for more info).

Therefore if the reason you're asking this question is so you can decided whether or not to make the column `UNIQUE` in a database, don't.

Comment: major error in the article - MD5 hashes are *sixteen* bytes long.  They're only 32 bytes long when hex encoded.

Comment: @Alnitakt It seems the author confused the string length being 32 chars with the number of bytes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the code *should* be unique, unless you're generating more than one per user per second. It's also terrifically **predictable**. If an attacker knows the id of a user and the *rough* time of when the code is being generated, it's trivial to guess the code. If the attacker is allowed an unlimited number of guesses, even the rough time doesn't really matter, as he could easily try all valid codes for the last couple of years.

You should really generate a *(pseudo) random* code instead of a code based on rather static data. On Linux, just read from `/dev/random`:

```
$code = bin2hex(file_get_contents('/dev/random', false, null, -1, 32));
                                                                  ^^
                                                          desired length/2
```